# Difference between the various XMPP MessageType(s)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I'm trying to figure out what are the various MessageType in Google App Engine XMPP Implementation. The [MessageType JavaDoc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/xmpp/MessageType.html) is totally lacking, actually many parts of GAE's JavaDocs are very poor.

I've tried googling, but could not find anything. Here is the list of MessageType:

```
CHAT           
ERROR          
GROUPCHAT           
HEADLINE       
NORMAL
```

I've seen people's code around using NORMAL, I don't understand what could be the difference between NORMAL and CHAT. Anyone can explain or point me to some good documentation?

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time with `XMPP: The Definitive Guide`. Reading from the RFCs is a chore, and I'm myself going through the book to explore XMPP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [RFC6121](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-syntax-type) :

**Chat :**

> The message is sent in the context of a one-to-one chat session. Typically an interactive client will present a message of type "chat" in an interface that enables one-to-one chat between the two parties, including an appropriate conversation history. Detailed recommendations regarding one-to-one chat sessions are provided under [Section 5.1](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-chat).

**Normal :**

> The message is a standalone message that is sent outside the context of a one-to-one conversation or groupchat, and to which it is expected that the recipient will reply. Typically a receiving client will present a message of type "normal" in an interface that enables the recipient to reply, but without a conversation history. The default value of the 'type' attribute is "normal".